# Can't update kernel because of full /boot partition, what is the proper way to remove older images? (Gentoo)

Tags: uefi, gentoo

On a Gentoo server, the EFI partition is full and it causes issues when trying to update the kernel.

An `ls` of /boot shows the following:

```
config-6.1.27-gentoo-dist     config-6.3.8-gentoo-dist          initramfs-6.3.4-gentoo-dist.img.old  System.map-6.3.3-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.1.27-gentoo-dist     vmlinuz-6.3.6-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.10-gentoo-dist     config-6.3.9-gentoo-dist          initramfs-6.3.5-gentoo-dist.img      System.map-6.3.4-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.10-gentoo-dist     vmlinuz-6.3.7-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.3-gentoo-dist      EFI                               initramfs-6.3.6-gentoo-dist.img      System.map-6.3.4-gentoo-dist.old  vmlinuz-6.3.11-gentoo-dist     vmlinuz-6.3.8-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.4-gentoo-dist      grub                              initramfs-6.3.7-gentoo-dist.img      System.map-6.3.5-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.12-gentoo-dist     vmlinuz-6.3.9-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.4-gentoo-dist.old  initramfs-6.1.27-gentoo-dist.img  initramfs-6.3.8-gentoo-dist.img      System.map-6.3.6-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.3-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.4.3-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.5-gentoo-dist      initramfs-6.3.10-gentoo-dist.img  initramfs-6.3.9-gentoo-dist.img      System.map-6.3.7-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.4-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.4.4-gentoo-dist
config-6.3.6-gentoo-dist      initramfs-6.3.3-gentoo-dist.img   System.map-6.1.27-gentoo-dist        System.map-6.3.8-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.4-gentoo-dist.old  vmlinuz-6.4.4-gentoo-dist.old
config-6.3.7-gentoo-dist      initramfs-6.3.4-gentoo-dist.img   System.map-6.3.10-gentoo-dist        System.map-6.3.9-gentoo-dist      vmlinuz-6.3.5-gentoo-dist
```

The currently booted kernel version is `6.1.27-gentoo-dist`.

What's the proper way to remove older images from the boot partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kernel/Removal:

```bash
$ emerge eclean-kernel
$ eclean-kernel -a
```

Thanks to @Artem S. Tashkinov.